# How many areas is reasonable for areaServed schema?

Tags: schema.org, spam, local-seo, json-ld, best-practices

I'm adding some schema to my site and was wondering about the areaServed property. Is this used for SEO in any way? If it is, is it good or bad to cram as much into it as possible?

i.e. if I simply added "Wolverhampton" (UK) as a city, would that be just the same as adding all the surrounding suburbs too? Would there be some benefit/harm in doing this?

```
"areaServed": [ "Wolverhampton"]

vs.

"areaServed": [ "Wolverhampton", "Wednesfield", "Bushbury", "Penn", "Bilston", "etc etc etc"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe any search engine has said they use areaServed yet.

If it is used by Google, my guess would be to help confirm GMB data. But I've not heard of it having any effect on the ranking of the page.

As there is no known consumers, there is also no known rules outside of sticking to the schema.org vocabulary.

I'd try to avoid including areas that are inside another area.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I won't bother putting too much effort into it for now then.

Answer (score 0):

> i.e. if I simply added "Wolverhampton" (UK) as a city, would that be
> just the same as adding all the surrounding suburbs too? Would there
> be some benefit/harm in doing this?

For the service area value, select the highest geolocation level. E.g., **[Wolverhampton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverhampton)**:

> is a city, metropolitan borough, and administrative centre in the West
> Midlands, England.

Probably the highest level for this city can be **[West Midlands (county)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Midlands_(county))** or higher.

Alternative: put the GeoShape type in this property and set your specific geo coordinates, e.g.:

- box
- circle
- line
- polygon

If this doesn't matter to your business, then give up the complexity of structured data as Tony McCreath recommended. For Google, it will be enough to indicate the relevant value of the address of your business.